# Why pass functions as children in React component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, still struggling in understanding the design of React component.
I saw some code as below:

```
export const ProModeContext = React.createContext();

export class XXX extends Component {
  ...
   render() {
      return <ProModeContext.Consumer>
              { contextData => {xxx }
             </ProModeContext.Consumer>
   }
}
```

and the pattern is

```
<Abc>
{
   param => {xxx}   // let's say this anonymous arrow function is called f1
}
</Abc>
```

so my questions are:

Q1- is `f1` a child of `Abc` component, therefore it can be accessed as `this.props.children` inside the component?

Q2-if `f1` is a child of `Abc` component, how `f1` get called inside the `Abc` component?

```
export class Abcextends Component {
   ...
   this.props.children???   //how to invoke `f1` internally?
}
```

since children props is not an array, we can't invoke `f1` as `this.props.children[0]()`

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually any valid JSX is a valid JavaScript function.
JavaScript functions accept JavaScript expressions or functions as arguments, which is roughly what's happening when you do

```
<h1>{ person.firstName }</h1>
```

Here you create a function `h1`, that accepts the argument `person.firstName`, again, roughly.

As to the question why it's not all `props`, if everything was props then it's be something akin to using callbacks.

By utilizing the parent-children pattern we can have a more declarative UI.

Now, why would we want to do this? There are a plethora of reasons but one good reason is that in some cases it's more concise where you don't want to declare a variable for a list of JSX items.

You asked the question about this pattern below:

```
<Abc propName={param => xxx}>
```

This pattern is called [a render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) - and it's great to use when you want to separate logic and rendering.

The declarative pattern and the render prop pattern serves different use cases and should be applied when necessary to the problem at hand and neither is a one size fits all solution.

Edit:
Your first example looks like this compiled from JSX to JavaScript

```
React.createElement(
    ABC, null, counts.map(count => React.createElement("p", null, count))
)
```

and the API for `createElement` looks like this:

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

Comment: Andesson   so for my example, the inner  function is a child of  `Abc` Component, is my understanding correct? and how can the function get invoked inside the component?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misinterpreting your question, you are asking about the [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern.

So render props are basically used when you want some render decisions in the child to be taken by the parent. Eg:

```
<DataProvider render={data => (
  <h1>Hello {data.target}</h1>
)} id={someId}/>
```

Here assume `DataProvider` is a component which just fetches data from some API based on `id`. Now what to render after fetch is decided by the `render` props. So the implementation for `DataProvider` would just be:

- Call API for `someId`.
- Call `render` prop function with the fetched data.

One usecase of this pattern is separation of concern. `DataProvider` is just concerned with fetching data. The parent is just concerned about rendering it. There are other use cases as well described in the official docs linked above.

Passing as children :

```
function Parent() {
  return (
    <Child>
      <div>Some child content</div>
    </Child>
  );
}

function Child({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Passing with render prop:

```
function Parent() {
  return <Child render={(text) => <div>Some child {text}</div>} />;
}

function ChildWithRenderProp({ render }) {
  return <div>{render('content')}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I know render props. So how can I invoke the inner function(as the child of a component)?

Comment: Just do `{this.props.children}` inside your child component. You cannot pass make any function call or pass any argument. That is the difference between a render prop and children.

Comment: Whatever `contextData` referenced inside parent comes from the parent's scope. The child does not provide any information to parent while rendering children.

Comment: sorry still confused.so how the function f1 gets called inside the Abc component? If you write me the code then I will understand